# Combining hobby paths for post action

Tags: tikz-pgf, hobby

Is there anyway to combine hobby paths and lines into a single path so that I can apply a post-action?

Basically, I want my orientation arrows to be equally spaced along the entire path rather than the individual components.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\tikzset{
  clockwise arrows/.style={
    postaction={
      decorate,
      decoration={
        markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 40pt with {\arrow{>}},
   }}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[framed]

\coordinate (B1) at (7,-1);
\coordinate (B2) at (7,1);

\coordinate (A1) at (1,2);
\coordinate (A2) at (1,-2);

\draw[magenta, thick, clockwise arrows] (A1) -- (A2);
\draw[magenta, thick, clockwise arrows] (B1) -- (B2);

\draw[magenta,thick,use Hobby shortcut, clockwise arrows] (B2) .. (4.5,2) .. (3,3) .. (A1);
\draw[magenta,thick,use Hobby shortcut, clockwise arrows] (A2) .. (3,-3) .. (4.5,-2) .. (B1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Note arrows are not equally spaced.]

Comment: What goes wrong if you just put them into a single path command?  That ought to work just fine.

Comment: How do I do that :S ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can combine your four `draw` statements into a single statement:

```
\draw[magenta,thick,use Hobby shortcut, clockwise arrows] 
    (B2) .. (4.5,2) .. (3,3) .. (A1) -- 
    (A2) .. (3,-3) .. (4.5,-2) .. (B1) -- cycle;
```

Note that you can mix `..` and `--` and that `cycle` closes the loop.

But, you will still get that horrible arrow at the start of the path.  To fix that you could just make the decoration start a bit further along:

```
    mark=between positions 0.05  and 1 step 40pt with {\arrow{>}},
```

with these changes your example produces this:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself!

Comment: @LoopSpace I'm sure you could.